# How can i cycle array values with next and previous button in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a vocabulary application and i want to cycle array values with next and previous buttons. I assigned values from Database and working. But i cant cycle between array values. Increasing working but i have to click several times to cycle previous value. I could not find the correct increment, decrement operator.

```
 int position = 0; 
`btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position >= array.length){
                position = 0;
                txtWord.setText(array[position][0]);
                position++;                    
            }else {
                txtWord.setText(array[position][0]);
                position++;                   
            }
        }
    });`

btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position >= 0){
                txtWord.setText(array[position--][0]);
            }else{
                position = array.length;
                txtWord.setText(array[position--][0]);
            }

        }
    });
```

Complete Code is here:

```
DatabaseHelper myDB;
TextView txtWord, txtNumberOfWords;
Button btnBack, btnShow, btnNext;
String[][] array;
int position = 0;
boolean showWord= true;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    txtWord = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtWord);
    txtNumberOfWords = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtNumberOfWords);
    btnBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
    btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnNext = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

    myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    Cursor data = myDB.getListContents();
    array = new String[data.getCount()][2];

    if(data.getCount() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There is no definition!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{

        data.moveToFirst();

        for(int i = 0; i < data.getCount(); i++){
                for(int y = 0; y < 2; y++){
                    array[i][y] = data.getString(1+y);
                }
                data.moveToNext();
            }
        txtWord.setText(array[0][0]);
        position = position + 1;
        txtNumberOfWords.setText(position  + " of " + array.length);
    }

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position >= array.length){
                position = 0;
                txtWord.setText(array[position][0]);
                position++;
                txtNumberOfWords.setText(position  + " of " + array.length);
            }else {
                txtWord.setText(array[position][0]);
                position++;
                txtNumberOfWords.setText(position  + " of " + array.length);
            }
            showWord = true;
        }
    });

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(position >= 0){
                txtWord.setText(array[position--][0]);
                txtNumberOfWords.setText(position  + " of " + array.length);
            }else{
                position = array.length;
                txtWord.setText(array[position--][0]);
                txtNumberOfWords.setText(position  + " of " + array.length);
            }

        }
    });

    btnShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(showWord){
                txtWord.setText(array[position-1][1]);
                showWord = false;
            }else{
                txtWord.setText(array[position-1][0]);
                showWord = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = (position + 1) % array.length;
            txtWord.setText(array[position][0]);
        }
    });

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            position = (position - 1) % array.length;
            txtWord.setText(array[position][0]);
        }
    });
```

There's also a bug, as you're using `position` as both the *TextView* - `txtNumberOfWords` and the array pointer. Those are different. For the TextView, display `position+1` and for the array use `position`. Don't forget to change your line of code from:

```
position = position + 1;
```

to this:

```
position = 0;
```

Comment: Its not working stable. For example Values jump from first to third.

Comment: Try setting position to 0, instead of position + 1;

Comment: the above code i wrote, works fine in the forward direction.

Comment: Yes, it's jumping from first to third because your position is set wrong. Set it to 0 before the clickListeners. And for the the textView (txtNumberOfWords), display position+1

Comment: Ohh finally, yes, increment and decrement working now. But when i try to come back from array [0][0] value, app crashes. No problem forward direction. It cycles correctly. Should i use if statement? For example if(position <= 0){ position = array.length;}. Thank you by the way.

Comment: Using modulus is better and more readable. Instead of % array.lenght try % data.getCount()

Comment: Also, if you found the answer useful, do you mind accepting it? Thanks